# BroadCast Receiver unregistered in OnPause result in listening issue to fcm notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create a chatting app using FCM notification. Once a notification comes we will send a broadcast request which can be used to notify the `recyclerview`. At this stage everything is working well.

But the situation, when the receiver got unregister within onPause method the `recyclerview` is not getting notified. So the latest comment doesn't appear in the `recyclerview`.

So my question is how we can tackle such scenario when receiver is getting unregistered automatically like screen lock or dialog appears nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you're missing data after onPause executes, the solution is to refresh the data in onResume.